# where is the button save on Juju gui

Tags: juju

Where is the button "save"? it's no longer present on Juju gui (Juju GUI at version 2.7.3). If I decide to configure of new parameters on a charm via Juju gui how do I can save that?

[image]

while on JAAS it's present

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI in Juju has been updated to 2.7.4 which has fixed this issue. To make that the command is the following:

```
$:juju upgrade-gui
fetching Juju GUI archive
uploading Juju GUI 2.7.4
upload completed
Juju GUI switched to version 2.7.4
```

[image]